# Images have positions altered when the window is maximised but the textboxes stay the same

Tags: html, css

How do I keep those images I made in the same place when I expand or shrink the window? I understand that there are similar functions, namely max-height and min-height that prevent the elements from shrinking or expanding below or above a certain height or width when the window is likewise expanded or shrunk, but I do not exactly understand how the above can be achieved

I plan to use the max-height and min-height contents for the elements but I would figure the "top:" element would be involved.

Below is the code as follows:

> ```
> <!DOCTYPE html>
>
> <html lang="en">
> <head>
>  <title> characters</title>
>  <meta charset="utf-8">
> </head>
>
> <body class="parallax">
>
> <link href="cssname.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
>
> <div>
> <h1><a href="x.html" class="goback">←Go Back</a>title1</h1>
>
> <h2 class="header1">header1</h2>
> <img src="image1.png" alt="image1" class="image1">
> <p class="text1">text</p>
>
> <h2 class="header2">header2</h2>
> <img src="image2.png" alt="image2" class="image2">
> <p class="text2">text</p>
>
> <h2 class="header3">header3</h2>
> <img src="image3.png" alt="image3" class="image3">
> <p class="text3">text</p>
>
>
> <h2 class="header4">header4</h2>
> <img src="image4.png" alt="image4" class="image4">
> <p class="text4">text</p>
>
>
>
>
>
> </div>
> </body>
>
> </html>
> ```

```
h1{
font-family: 'Quicksand';
text-align: center;
position: relative;
background: antiquewhite;
border: 5px solid bisque;
}

.image1 {
left: 400;
position: absolute;
right: 60%;
height: 250px;
}

.image2 {
position: absolute;
right: 20%;
top: 59%;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
height: 250px;
}

.image3 {
position: absolute;
right: 60%;
top: 92%;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
height: 250px;
}

.image4 {
position: absolute;
right: 20%;
top: 130%;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
height: 250px;
}

.goback{
float: left;
display: indent-block;
position: relative;
margin-top: 25px;
font-size: 20px;
}

.text1 {
color: darkgoldenrod;
font-family: 'Quicksand';
font-size: 18px;
top: -100;
float: right;
left: 100;
position: relative;
background: antiquewhite;
width: 60%;
border: 5px solid bisque;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
line-height: 1.5;
}

.header1 {
color: darkgoldenrod;
font-family: 'Quicksand';
font-size: 30px;
top: 800;
float: right;
left: 100;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
position: relative;
background: antiquewhite;
width: 60%;
border: 5px solid bisque;
line-height: 1.5;
}



.text2 {
color: darkgoldenrod;
font-family: 'Quicksand';
font-size: 18px;
top: -100;
float: left;
left: 100;
position: relative;
background: antiquewhite;
width: 60%;
border: 5px solid bisque;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
line-height: 1.5;
}

.header2 {
color: darkgoldenrod;
font-family: 'Quicksand';
font-size: 30px;
top: 800;
float: left;
left: 100;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
position: relative;
background: antiquewhite;
width: 60%;
border: 5px solid bisque;
line-height: 1.5;
}

.header4 {
color: darkgoldenrod;
font-family: 'Quicksand';
font-size: 30px;
top: 800;
float: left;
left: 100;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
position: relative;
background: antiquewhite;
width: 60%;
border: 5px solid bisque;
line-height: 1.5;
}

.text4 {
color: darkgoldenrod;
font-family: 'Quicksand';
font-size: 18px;
top: -100;
float: left;
left: 100;
position: relative;
background: antiquewhite;
width: 60%;
border: 5px solid bisque;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
line-height: 1.5;
}

.header3 {
color: darkgoldenrod;
font-family: 'Quicksand';
font-size: 30px;
top: 800;
float: right;
left: 100;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
position: relative;
background: antiquewhite;
width: 60%;
border: 5px solid bisque;
line-height: 1.5;
}

.text3 {
color: darkgoldenrod;
font-family: 'Quicksand';
font-size: 18px;
top: -100;
float: right;
left: 100;
position: relative;
background: antiquewhite;
width: 60%;
border: 5px solid bisque;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
line-height: 1.5;
}


.parallax{
background-image: url("bg.png");
min-height: 300px;
height: 200px;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
}
```

and here is a crude representation of the issue, where t = textbox, i = image, yellowcircle = windowmode and greencircle = fullscreen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmcDA.jpg

Any help would be graciously appreciated

see the post above for tried and expected

Answer (score 0):

The reason is probably because you are using `position: absolute` for all your images.

`absolute` is positioned relative to the nearest positioned ancestor (instead of positioned relative to the viewport, like fixed).
If an absolute positioned element has no positioned ancestors, it uses the document body, and moves along with page scrolling.

By the structure of your HTML, your image will position them relative to `document.body`.

You could try to change `absolute` to `relative` and place all your images to desired position, also meaning you have to remove `top` and `right` property.